# Сравнить данные по столбцу A, B в df1 с столбцом A, B в df2 и выбрать свободное число из списка в столбце C df2

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть два больших dataFrame. По df1 я прохожусь циклом по строчно и если срабатывает нужное мне условие,то в этой стркое мне нужно сравнить данные по столбцу A, B с столбцом A, B в df2 и  выбрать свободное число ( из отрезка чисел 129 - 200 ) в колонке C. это Число нужно присвоить переменной Free_Numb и записать в df2 колонку С

Вводные данные ниже:

```
Free_Numb = 0
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [501, 501, 501, 501, 502, 501, 723, 712, 123, 501],
                   'B': [1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 7 ,8 ,8, 1],})
                   

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [501,502,503,501,501]
                   'B': [1,15,17,1,1]
                   'C': [[1, 129, 130, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141], 
                        [1, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152], 
                        [1, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 152, 153, 154, 155]]

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
```

Comment: А по какому условию вы сравниваете столбцы в двух датафреймах?

Comment: @strawdog Условие в цикле for index, row in df1.iterrows(): не относиться к второму датафрейму. Оно отбирает нужные мне строки ( так как строк много и мне нужны не все). Идея такова  - Если Данные df A[1] и B[1] сходятся с данными какой-то из строк  df2 A, B, то выбрать свободное число из колонки df2 C

Comment: Не надо `iterrows`, всё обычно можно сделать *векторно*, нужно только сформулировать критерии: 1) какие строки вас интересуют, по какому критерию 2) как сопоставлять датафреймы, по каким полям/условиям 3) что нужно сделать с сопоставленными ячейками

Comment: @CrazyElf Мой скрипт достаточно большой, он имеет 700 строк, там много условий) это лишь одно из них и вся работа этого скрипта построена на iterrows. Я не могу закинуть сюда весь свой скрипт, из за конфиденциальности. В вводных данных выше я ввёл абстрактные данные. На самом деле их намного больше. Мне подойдут любые варианты решения(не обязательно через iterrows), я попробую их интегрировать в свой скрипт

Comment: @CrazyElf 1.Допустим это будут строки в которых колонка A = 501. 2. Найти в df2 строку в которой df1[A,B] == df2[A,B] 3. В найденой строке есть колонка С в котором есть список. В списке нужно найти свободную позицию в промежутке чисел 129-200 ( допустим для первой строки DF1 это будет 131 ). Записать число 131 в переменную Free_Numb и в этот же список. Для второй второй строки DF2 число 131 уже будет занято и подобраться должно 142

Comment: Что-то слишком сложно. Может MaxU уважаемый появится и разберётся, я пас. Там всё просто должно быть, но думать всё-равно нужно